# mouse pointer appears to scroll the windows desktop

Tags: windows-7

I have a Lenovo w520 running at 1920x1080.  When I take the mouse pointer, go to the windows desktop move the pointer at the top of the desktop, the desktop appears to scroll downwards, as if the actual desktop is larger than the screen shows.  The result is that the desktop icons are scrolled downwards; and some icons end up off the screen.

Is there a way to fix this issue so that the desktop fits onto the window exactly and so that icons cannot be scrolled off screen?

Comment: Did you accidentally turn on Windows Magnifier? Press WINDOWS key + ESC key and see if anything changes. More likely solution: try reinstalling the graphics driver.

Comment: windows magnifier not an issue

Comment: ...and reinstalling the driver?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by selecting a higher resolution than your laptop screen can display.

Check what the native resolution of your display is.
Then right clock on the desktop, go to 'screen resolution' and select that value.

Comment: thanks, I have seen this in the past as well, and looked into this, but even at lower resolutions, the issue occurs.

Comment: Is there any virtual desktop software installed?

Comment: there is no virtual desktop software intalled